# Not possible to use shorthand route handlers if RestSerializer is used? (ember-cli-mirage)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I set up a simple [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/cf8020df67b8e0ecd3e44c591934a4fe?openFiles=mirage.serializers.application.js%2C&route=%2Fshops%2F1%2Fedit) to show you my error that is occurring when trying to update a model.
It's considerable that I'm using `ember-cli-mirage` for mocking the data.
According to the docs, I created a shorthand route that should handle the PUT request.
It does, but with the error: `Your handler for the url /api/shops/1 threw an error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

When using the JSONAPISerializer, everything is working with shorthands (`mirage/config.js`) and I'm able to update models, but in my case I have to use the `RESTSerializer` with serialized IDs in the responses.
The request payload when I'm sending the model's `attrs` are without `Id` at the end of the property name, f.e.:

`// attrs object in PUT request
{
  name: "Shop 1",
  city: "1" // belongsTo relationship,
}`

Now Mirage is trying to find those properties on the respective database model that has to be updated, but cannot find it, because in the database it's `cityId` and not just `city`...

I also found this [issue report](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/issues/972) and it’s working, but I was hoping I could avoid something like this. As far as I can remember, in previous versions of ember-cli-mirage (v0.1.x) it was also not needed to override the normalize method in the serializer to be able to make use of the RestSerializer with serializedIds…

**My question is**:
Is there a way to stick to shorthand route handlers only, or do I really have to write a helper or other custom solution only because I have to use the RestSerializer?
That would be really sad, but at least I would know then.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: I do not know the answer, but you may want to note the version of mirage you want to use.

Comment: I want to use a version that contains support for factories and automatic model detection. But when I tried the first version that contained both of these features, it was also behaving like I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it looks like you need the custom serializer for now until the bug fix for it is merged.

Long answer: that issue looks to be an issue that occurred in the 0.2 -> 0.3 upgrade for Mirage, likely because of underlying DB changes made in Mirage. It'll probably get fixed, but for now you'll need to work around it.